# Is it possible to use 'chunksize=' option in Pandas.ReadSQL to limit/cap the memory/RAM usage?

Tags: python, pandas, cx-oracle, in-memory

I am trying to load 200 million rows of data from an Oracle Database into a pandas dataframe using the cx_Oracle package as:

```
import cx_Oracle


conct = cx_Oracle.connect(self.dbuser, self.dbpassword, cx_Oracle.makedsn(self.host, self.port, self.sid))

query= """
      SELECT  *
      FROM IDS
      """

df = pd.read_sql(query, con=conct)

return df
```

I have a concern:

1) RAM over head: Upon monitoring the RAM usage, I notice that python holds up all the memory needed for the entire 200 million rows while building the dataframe. I am trying to limit/cap the RAM usage by utilizing the chunksize option albeit unsuccessfully. Here's what I am trying:

```
# Create empty list
dfl = []  

# Create empty dataframe
dfs = pd.DataFrame()  

# Start Chunking
for chunk in pd.read_sql(query, con=conct, ,chunksize=10000000):

    # Start Appending Data Chunks from SQL Result set into List
    dfl.append(chunk)

# Start appending data from list to dataframe
dfs = pd.concat(dfl, ignore_index=True)
```

But technically, for the RAM I am freeing up after every chunk pull, arent I re-allocating it to the list that is cumulatively holding the chunk(s)?

Is there a way to truly limit / cap the RAM usage/hold for large data hauls using the pd.rad_sql method or is there an alternate way to achieve this?